# Grouping by number of occurrences of a repeatable value in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Lets assume we have a table like this.

```
      id  name  value

      1    x     12

      2    x     23

      3    y     47

      4    x     18

      5    y     29

      6    z     45

      7    y     67
```

Doing a normal group by name would yield us

select name,count(*) from table group by name;

```
     name  count(*)

      x      3
      y      3
      z      1
```

I want to get the reverse.. ie. grouping the number of names that occur a set number of times. I want my output to be

```
     count    number of elements occuring count times
       1              1
       3              2
```

Is it possible to do this using just a single query? Another way is to use a temp table but I dont want to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need one more `group by`:

```
select cnt, count(*), min(name), max(name)
from (select name, count(*) as cnt
      from table
      group by name
     ) n
group by cnt
order by 1;
```

I do these types of histogram queries all the time.  The `min()` and `max()` provide sample data.  This is useful to understand outliers and unexpected values.

Answer (score 0):

You can `GROUP BY` *twice*, e.g.

```
with
  Names as (
    select name as name,
           count(1) as cnt
      from MyTable
  group by name)

  select count(1),
         cnt 
    from Names
group by cnt
```